# Deserialization feature on codehaus jackson ObjectReader

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

How can I apply deserialization  feature (FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES) for a object reader ? I know how it can be done for a objectMapper but, how to do it on a objectReader  in codehaus jackson ?

Comment: Why didnt you use ObjectMapper itself?

Comment: @TomSebastian  
I have the mapper object declared as static and the same mapper object is being using in different methods. In my method I don't want to set the configuration as it affects all the other mapper objects used in the class. So can I create a mapper reader and use the configuration only for that reader in my method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since some version Jackson introduced [`ObjectReader#with`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/) method that implements what you want. Maybe it will be easier to move to higher version.

However, if you can not use higher version, you can set this feature with [`ObjectMapper#configure`](http://www.javadocs.com/docs/com.ovea/jetty-session-redis/1.0/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.java#configure%28org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.Feature,%20boolean%29) method. After you set this feature to `true` you can create `ObjectReader` from `ObjectMapper` with [`reader`](http://www.javadocs.com/docs/com.ovea/jetty-session-redis/1.0/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.java#reader%28java.lang.Class%29) method.

As you can see in docs for the `ObjectReader` you cannot change its features after creation. But readers does not share mappers state. So if you need to create multiple readers from one mapper and only few of them need this option you can set features in `ObjectMapper` only for them. You can get current state of the feature like this

```
boolean enabled = mapper.getDeserializationConfig().isEnabled(feature);
```

change state and then return it to the original state. See `createReader(Class<T> clazz, DeserializationConfig.Feature feature)` method in example.

This is the POJO that we will deserialize

```
class ExamplePojo {
    private int a1;
    private String b1;

    public ExamplePojo() {

    }

    public ExamplePojo(int a1, String b1) {
        this.a1 = a1;
        this.b1 = b1;
    }

    public int getA1() {
        return a1;
    }

    public void setA1(int a1) {
        this.a1 = a1;
    }

    public String getB1() {
        return b1;
    }

    public void setB1(String b1) {
        this.b1 = b1;
    }
}
```

And here is the example

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectReader;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException;

public class JacksonExample {

    static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static <T> ObjectReader createReader(Class<T> clazz, DeserializationConfig.Feature feature) {
        boolean enabled = mapper.getDeserializationConfig().isEnabled(feature);

        mapper.configure(feature, true);
        ObjectReader reader = mapper.reader(clazz);
        mapper.configure(feature, enabled);

        return reader;
    }

    public static <T> ObjectReader createReader(Class<T> clazz) {
        return mapper.reader(clazz);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // by default turn off this feature
        mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        // Should fail
        ObjectReader r1 = createReader(ExamplePojo.class, DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        try {
            ExamplePojo ex = r1.readValue("{\"a1\":1,\"b1\":\"Hello!\",\"c1\":1}");
            System.out.println(ex.getA1() + " " + ex.getB1());
        } catch (UnrecognizedPropertyException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        // Should be ok
        ObjectReader r2 = createReader(ExamplePojo.class);
        try {
            ExamplePojo ex = r2.readValue("{\"a1\":2,\"b1\":\"Hello!\",\"c1\":2}");
            System.out.println(ex.getA1() + " " + ex.getB1());
        } catch (UnrecognizedPropertyException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        // Should fail
        try {
            ExamplePojo ex = r1.readValue("{\"a1\":3,\"b1\":\"Hello!\",\"c1\":3}");
            System.out.println(ex.getA1() + " " + ex.getB1());
        } catch (UnrecognizedPropertyException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        // Should be ok
        try {
            ExamplePojo ex = r2.readValue("{\"a1\":4,\"b1\":\"Hello!\",\"c1\":4}");
            System.out.println(ex.getA1() + " " + ex.getB1());
        } catch (UnrecognizedPropertyException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And the output for this example

> Unrecognized field "c1" (Class ExamplePojo), not marked as ignorable at [Source: java.io.StringReader@7c30a502; line: 1, column: 29] (through reference chain: ExamplePojo["c1"])
>
> 2 Hello!
>
> Unrecognized field "c1" (Class ExamplePojo), not marked as ignorable  at [Source: java.io.StringReader@49e4cb85; line: 1, column: 29] (through reference chain: ExamplePojo["c1"])
>
> 4 Hello!

Comment: I have the mapper object declared as static and the same mapper object is being using in different methods. In my method I don't want to set the configuration  as it affects all the other mapper objects used in the class.  So can I create a mapper reader and use the configuration only for that reader?

Comment: @hck3r I have update my answer. You can set features in mapper, create reader and then return feature to the original state.

Comment: the above method works fine, but the other mapper objects in the class I cannot change them  to use createReader. The other mapper objects already use `mapper.readValue(json,class)`. I just have to make changes in  my method.

Comment: @hck3r I have updated my answer (see first paragraph). Also I have not understand what is the problem exactly, maybe you can provide some example?